# If the operator is not the CAMO who is responsible?

Tags: easa-regulations, easa

If the operator does not have a  Continuing Airworthiness Management Organisation (CAMO) and it contracts out its CAMO functions, does the operator remain responsible for the aircraft or does the contracted CAMO relieve some of that responsibility?

Comment: Please clarify what CAMO is.

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating here, so standing by to be corrected by those in knowledge of facts!

It might be a good idea to study applicable regulations as well as the CAMO (Continuing Airworthiness Management Organisation) agreement in question; however operational responsibility will surely lie with the operator.

Sense test: If an aircraft ends up as a smoking hole somewhere, it most likely won’t do for the operator to say „that’s tough, but it wasn’t us, it was just the CAMO“.

Answer (score 0):

You can contract out the authority to perform certain functions.  You can never contract out 100% of the responsibility.

If something happens you can be sure the operator will be named in the inevitable lawsuit.